# How to decode the byte value

Tags: c#, encryption, c#-4.0

How to decode the below the line, `Queryval` is a `StringBuilder`.

```
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(QueryVal + "$");
```

Comment: `string decoded = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outStream);`

Answer (score 1):

```
string QueryValString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outStream);
```